# Lightnig:input checkbox did not store value to object attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Customobject__c" />

 <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="test1" label="Complex Track" 
  value="{!v.record.Complex_Case__c}" 
  onchange="{!c.onValueChanged}"/><br/>
                        
<lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="ftTrack" label="Fast Track" 
value="{!v.record.Fast_Track_Case__c}" onchange="{!c.onValueChanged}"/><br/>
```

**controller**

```
onValueChanged{
//Trying to print the custom object record whether it is holding value, but //both of the below script return NULL

console.log(' value1 ', c.find('test1').get("v.value"));
console.log('record changed : ', JSON.stringify(c.get("v.record")));
}
```

I have to get the checked checkboxes in controller so that i can perform some validation on that.

Please help me to understand if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, and thus Aura/LWC frameworks, the `value` property of a checkbox is the value to submit to the server if the box is checked and you're using a form with a submit button. To determine if the checkbox is actually checked, use the `checked` attribute.

```
c.find('test1').get("v.checked"))
```

Also, that means you need to bind to `checked` in your markup:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="test1" label="Complex Track" 
checked="{!v.record.Complex_Case__c}" 
onchange="{!c.onValueChanged}"/>
```

Comment: <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="test1" label="Complex Track" 
  checked="{!v.record.Complex_Case__c}" 
  onchange="{!c.onValueChanged}"/><br/>    i have tried this as well but the onchange did not invoke then. My aim is to store the checked value in an Sobjet record and pass it to the apex controller for further processing

Comment: Thanks much for the input, am able to trigger the onchange using checked attribute. only think i will be doing onchange is to validate is both checkboxes are checked and throw an error if so, and i need to store the checkbox value (true/false) to the sobject variable. Do i have to specifically assign the values in onchange function?

Comment: In Aura, days binding is usually two way. You shouldn't need to assign the value to the record directly.